# how to let int 3 interrupt break on VectoredExceptionHandler in vs2019?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, hook

i have this kind of code , i hope vs2019 will break on TopLevelHandler when i use interrupt execption.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool CaughtVEHDebugger = false;
void IllegalInst()
{
    char* ptr = 0;
    *ptr = 0;
    

}
LONG CALLBACK TopLevelHandler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* info)
{
    if (info->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP) //Detects when a VEH debugger single-steps through code
        CaughtVEHDebugger = true;

    printf("Executed toplevelhandler, Exception: %X\n", info->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode); //print any other exceptions we encounter
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main()
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, TopLevelHandler);
    //IllegalInst();
    __asm {INT 3};
    if (CaughtVEHDebugger)
        printf("Caught VEH debugger: %s\n", ((CaughtVEHDebugger > 0) ? "true" : "false"));

    return 0;
}
```

Windows process the exception as follow:
if receiving the exception, Windows first checks whether the process that issued the exception is in the debugging . If there is no debugger, the exception will be sent to the VEH exception handling function. If it has not been processed by VEH, check whether it is SEH  SEH, then to UEH, and finally to VCH.

In summary: Debugger>VEH>SEH>UEH>VCH.

i follow this url,and modify the execption setting ,vs2019 break on TopLevelHandler when i test with IllegalInst() ,but not work well  when i test it  with __asm {INT 3} code
[How to not break when user handled exception is thrown in visual studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844267/how-to-not-break-when-user-handled-exception-is-thrown-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: actually,i found this post quite similer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293208/leave-int3-breaks-to-applications-exception-handler-on-visual-studio